# Change comment location WordPress

Tags: wordpress, themes, comments

I am using free WordPress theme called ["Cosimo" by CrestaProject](https://wordpress.org/themes/cosimo/).

after styling the theme,
[my comment area look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHHDK.png).

but I want to change the way response comment look,
[i want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8ZM8.png).

I mean the response in the post will automatically be on the side of the comment, not below.

I hope I've succeeded to explain myself.

Thanks for the helpers!

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the original question.

Comment: Of course I was looking for an answer to my question before I asked here... my website is location localhost so unfortunately i cant send my website link but you can download the cosimo theme with the link on the topic and see the whole theme code. I just dont know which code to send here.. I mean that i need the respond comment will be automatically next to each other..

Comment: Nobody should have to download a theme to help you troubleshoot your problem.  If you can't isolate your problem to specific code, then I strongly suggest you hire a qualified developer.

Answer (score 0):

As per screenshot, you need to check your div for the comment section.

Comment: oh, i can't find the div line in code but.. I found the class in style.css file.
if change the class like this:               

.children {position:relative; left: 180px;}

Then the comments look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOwWp.png

And its not looking good... =\

Comment: You need to change the structure without it this could not be possible

Comment: Can you share the html structure here. How you take this screenshot

Comment: Thank you for fast responding, But actually i don't know what part of the html code is needed. you can see preview or download the theme files to see the whole code Here: https://wordpress.org/themes/cosimo/

Comment: As per cosimo theme demo, I have not seen any column structure in the comment section. I think you modified comment section. for better understand can you please share your website link or HTML structure?

Comment: Thank you for responding. my website is location localhost so unfortunately i cant send my website link but you can download the cosimo theme and see the whole theme code. I just dont know which code to send here..
I mean that i need the respond comment will be automatically next to each other..